# Connecting Multiple Points

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I wanted to ask if there is a way to connect multiple points using one line just like in a line graph, instead of using 1 line to connect A and B and then another line to connect B and C. is there a way to connect A B C using only one line?

[image: 2 Lines connecting the points]

[image: 1 Line connecting the points]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of the `x` or `y` values of a `line` at any time you want.

For example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

var cond = true

new_line = line.new(bar_index - 1, low[1] * 0.95, bar_index, high * 1.05, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid)

if cond
    cond := false
    line.set_xy2(new_line, bar_index, high * 1.05)
    line.set_xy1(new_line, bar_index - 1, low[1] * 0.95)
else
    cond := true
    line.set_xy1(new_line, bar_index - 1, high[1] * 1.05)
    line.set_xy2(new_line, bar_index, low * 0.95)
```

This code will give you one line that will look like this:

[image]